# What is the general approach to fixing Go To functionality in Resharper

Tags: resharper

I often see that some of the ReSharper functionality just doesn't work until you restart VS and reopen the project. But this situation I have now is consistent across restarts. So I am using a Go To Everything fuctionality often. It is enabled in ReSharper settings.

But since yesterday Go To Everything (Ctrl + N for me) can't find most of the files in the project (though it can find some).

Here is a screenshot of the problem:

I have that file open in editor just to prove that it's there. I show it found in an open solution in file tree. But ReSharper doesn't seem to be able to find it.

What to I do to troubleshoot. Thanks you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do here is to raise an issue with JetBrains. Either log a bug with the [issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com), or email resharper-support@jetbrains.com. Include details about what version of ReSharper you're using, what type of projects you're using, version of Visual Studio, etc.

However, from that screenshot, it looks like ReSharper isn't configured to analyse that file - there's no "green tick" in the scrollbar. Is ReSharper disabled? Is that file excluded from analysis? (Mind you, even when it's excluded, it should still show up in go to results. Something odd is happening here, support should be able to help better than StackOverflow)